# What does an SSRS filter do in terms of data processing?

Tags: ssrs-2012

Trying to understand how filtering works in SSRS.  My guess is that the dataset will return all rows and then the filters will be applied by SSRS.  Is that correct, or are the filters passed through to the dataset at runtime, so that only rows matching the filters are returned.

Does it depend on the Query type in SSRS - store procedure, Text, Table?

Thanks

Comment: your right; all data is returned by SMS; and then ssrs applies filter(s) to that dataset. It is report server intensive as all data is passed to report server to do what it wishes. If you are going this route ; using SP would be ideal as the execution plan is stored on server. Table, matrix are format(s) data is rendered in and can consume data from either a query, or SP. Finally, you can pass filters to query, and or SP (case sensitive on rs side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSRS dataset will fetch all rows the underlying query produces. Filters configured in SSRS are applied after the rows are retrieved. In the description of [SSRS filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-dataset-filters-data-region-filters-and-group-filters?view=sql-server-2017) from Microsoft it states "To filter data before it is retrieved, changed the query for each dataset."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It exists many ways to filter data in SSRS

Main points are:

1. Directly in the query when you create te dataset. You won't need to filter the dataset. In this case, data you're getting in the dataset are already filtered. About process time, I think you'll get the best result. Because you're filtering when you execute the query of the dataset.
2. If you have no control on the dataset, you can filter in a few location in the report : Dataset level, tablix level

Take a look about the point 6 following this link : [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3659/sql-server-reporting-services-best-practices-for-performance-and-maintenance/](http://SSRS%20best%20practices%20for%20performance)